# Redmine 3.3.2 How to Import Active Directory Users

Tags: import, active-directory, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am using Redmine 3.3.2 and I want to import my Active Users to Redmine.
I saw that there is a plugin for that but it can not be installed properly - [Redmine Ldap Sync](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_ldap_sync)

Are there any other free plugins or some other scripts to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think if you described the problems you are running into with the plugin you mentioned it might be possible to get this working for you.

Comment: @jkraemer I installed the plugin Redmine Ldap Sync [link] http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_ldap_sync as described. All seems to be successful. But After that when I go to Administration and select the plugin (translation missing: en.label_ldap_synchronization) http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img923/2870/djlrJV.png, I got the next error  http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8608/M84b5q.png
When I go to Administration->Plugins I see that the plugin is installed http://imageshack.com/a/img924/4105/2zRoj9.png
Don't know what is the problem :(

Comment: try the latest version from github: https://github.com/thorin/redmine_ldap_sync
For me the admin screen appears to work, then.

Comment: @jkraemer  - strange... till now I donload it from Git as a zip, after that unzip it to the local machine and after that copy to the linux distribution. And I got the errors above. Now I run git clone git://github.com/thorin/redmine_ldap_sync.git
I installed it and now it's ok 
Can not understand where was the problem